# Relationship between cosines of angles in 4 dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

If the cosine of the angle between the vectors $a$ and $b$ is $x$ and the cosine of the angle between the vectors $a$ and $p$ is $y$, then, if we call $z$ the cosine of the angle between the vectors $b$ and $p$, can we write $z$ in terms of $x$ and $y$?

All vectors are in $4$-dimensional Euclidean space.

Comment: No. You can apply any rotation to $p$ that keeps $a$ invariant without changing either the angle $x$ between $a$ and $b$ nor the angle $y$ between $a$ and $p$. But such a rotation *will* generally change the angle $z$ between $b$ and $p$.

Comment: @fgp: to me your comment sounds like a good answer. I would welcome it posted as such, so we can get this out of the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can apply any rotation to p that keeps a invariant without changing either the angle x between a and b nor the angle y between a and p. But such a rotation will generally change the angle z between b and p.

(This was initially a comment, I reposted it as an answer by MvG's request)

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. Do you mean that $z$ has no dependence whatsoever on $x$ and $y$?

Comment: $z$ is certainly not a *function* of $x$ and $y$, i.e. $x$ and $y$ don't uniquely determine $z$. I guess you can *bound* $z$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, though - it seems that for small angles $x$ and $y$, the angle $z$ must be small too.